# Python memory management

Tags: python, garbage-collection, binary-tree

Say I have a binary tree which contains pointers at each node going to the parent and the child, and I want to remove some part of an internal subtree, patching the remainder of the tree back together in a sensible way.

Does Python know to garbage collect the discarded piece of the subtree, even though the nodes within reference each other? I would expect this to be a capability of all languages which use garbage collection, but I don't know enough about garbage collection to know for sure. The best I have done myself is a smart (C++) pointer system which was not smart enough to handle the case I described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Python will discard the unreferenced nodes in the tree.

CPython uses *reference counting* to do most of is garbage collection. In your case, one or more of the tree nodes will have no references left, so they will be freed. Then the nodes that were pointed to by the freed node may have no references, and those will be freed too. Recursively, all unreferenced nodes will be freed.

CPython also has a garbage collector that can collect unreferenced *cycles*. These can't (easily) be detected using reference counting, but the cycle collector can identify and free them.

Other implementations of Python such as IronPython or Jython use different garbage collector schemes.

Comment: Does python (not just cpython) detect unreferenced cycles as well? It's not just a single node I'm removing, but a potentially large subtree which contains many cycles by construction.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: I see. I don't usually call the default Python "CPython". My mistake.

Comment: Ah, sorry I sometimes forget that it's not actually called that (except in the context of discussing multiple implementations, to distinguish the language from an implementation).